# Basic React element doesn't show in Rails 5.1 with webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I have a rails 5.1 app, with React installed via webpack, and the webpacker gem.  I have one react component working after following the example in 'Agile Web Development With Rails 5.1` (It just shows a different number of text inputs based on the users choice in a select drop down).  However, I'm now looking to expand my use of React in the site, but am now struggling to get even the most basic component to show, and fear I am missing something fundamental about how it all pieces together.

**app/javascript/hello.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**app/pages/about.html.erb**

```
//...
<div id="root"></div>
//...
```

The only way I get it to show, is by also placing `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello' %>` somewhere in the `about.html.erb`.Is that correct?  Will I have a pack_tag for each and every component I create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding:

`<%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello' %>`

to your `application.html.erb` file. It'll include the package to all pages, but whether or not a component renders will depend on whether or not it finds the element in which you tell it to render itself.

Comment: Yep that certainly works.  Doesn't that mean you could have tens (even hundreds) in `application.html.erb`. How does that impact on performance?

Comment: "Doesn't that mean you could have tens (even hundreds) in application.html.erb" - ten or hundreds of what?